# REACT AXIOS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Пробую React. Запрос на локалке к стороннему api через axios возвращает:
Failed to load http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=4eb78b09ae5168929d6d8e623d13749f&q=Moscow: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
Может кто нибудь на пальцах объяснить как это пофиксить?
Делаю запрос к погодному API на React:

```
var axios = require('axios');

const OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=4eb78b09ae5168929d6d8e623d13749f';

module.exports = {
    getTemp: function (location){
        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
        var requestUrl = `${OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL}&q=${encodedLocation}`;

        return axios.get(requestUrl).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.cod && res.data.message){
                throw new Error(res.data.message);
            } else {
                return res.data.main.temp;
            }
        }, function (res){
            throw new Error(res.data.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: почитайте про [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). ну или другими словами, пока ваш сторонний API не будет отдавать заголовки access-control, данных вы с него не получите. Решением может быть реализация на своем сервере скрипта-прокси, вы обращаетесь к своему, а он запрашивает у апи, он то уже может это сделать без всяких заголовков. там обычный get-запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы решить эту проблему, сервер должен отправлять

> A**ccess-Control-Allow-Origin** - заголовок

с вашим домейн именем, то есть таким образом он будет разрешать вашему домейну делать запрос.

Эту проблему можно обойти, делая запрос сначало прокси серверу. В вашем случае это будет выглядить вот так, думаю вам должно это помочь:

```
var axios = require('axios');

const OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=4eb78b09ae5168929d6d8e623d13749f';

module.exports = {
    getTemp: function (location){
        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
        var requestUrl = `${OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL}&q=${encodedLocation}`;
        const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"; // new line
        return axios.get(proxy + requestUrl).then(function (res) {
                if (res.data.cod && res.data.message){
                throw new Error(res.data.message);
            } else {
                return res.data.main.temp;
            }
        }, function (res){
            throw new Error(res.data.message);
        });
    }
}
```